# What is this shrub like plant?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, flowers

Found this on whidbey island in puget sound in Washington, USA. It seems to grow well in rainy coastal climates. About 3-4 ft/0.9-1.2 meters tall and same wide. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like *Centranthus ruber* (aka red valerian). If it likes you, it will self-seed, sometimes to the extent to become a nuisance. More information [here](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/93739/Centranthus-ruber/Details).

Comment: Too funny. I hope it doesn’t like me too much.